# IntelliJ Karma plugin: how to suppress debug output?

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, karma-runner

I'm having an Angular app and when I run unit tests using the Karma-plugin for IntelliJ I see console.debug outputs in the TestRun-tab. I want to hide those. In karma.conf.js I have stated:
`browserConsoleLogOptions: { level: 'info' }`
and it takes affect in the Karma Server-tab but not in the Test Run-tab. Any ideas how to supress debug prints also there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the Intellij karma reporter doesn't respect this option. I've replicated the issue and created a new ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-62839/Karma-specified-browserConsoleLogOptions-log-level-is-not-respected. Please vote for it to get notified on any progress

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I will vote.